# error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I tried to build the **Pixel Intensity Comparison-based Object detection (pico)** code in opencv 3.0, while building i got an error like   **error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' undeclared (first use in this function)** . Can any tell how to overcome these issues?? The code is as follows along with the error i got

```
float getticks()
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) < 0)
    {
        printf("clock_gettime error\n");

        return -1.0f;
    }

    return ts.tv_sec + 1e-9f*ts.tv_nsec;
}
```

and the error i got as

```
picolrn.c:94:18: error: storage size of 'ts' isn't known
  struct timespec ts;
                  ^
picolrn.c:96:19: error: 'CLOCK_MONOTONIC' undeclared (first use in this function)
  if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts) < 0)
                   ^
picolrn.c:96:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/picolrn.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't included the header where these entities are declared (e.g. time.h). Can you show what you have `#include`'ed?

Comment: I believe that code is linux-specific, and that the surrounding preprocessing code is wrong. Since you're apparently on Windows, I would try replacing the `#if __GNUC__` before that function with `#if 0`.

Comment: maybe make it `#if __linux__` instead of the `#if __GNUC__` , so at least it compiles correctly with mingw ( also, for the sample, might as well throw out the whole function, and use cv::getTickCount() and cv::getTickFrequency() )

Answer (score 11):

Add a commandline switch: `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L` when compiling.

Without it, time.h header will not define it.

Comment: what does this mean?